# Picasso - how to fetch image sequentially

Tags: android, picasso

I wanna retrieve images in Picasso for later and keep them in cache, at the moment I use this code:

```
        for(int i=0; i<urlList.size(); i++) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(url.get(i))
                    .fetch();
        }
```

but I wanna retrieve them sequentially. What's the best for that?

Answer (score -1):

You can load the image into a `Target`, if you have an array of your urls you can recursively load them from the `Target`.

Example activity that does this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    private ArrayList<String> urls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        urls = new ArrayList<>();
        urls.add("http://placehold.it/300&text=0");
        urls.add("http://placehold.it/300&text=1");
        urls.add("http://placehold.it/300&text=2");
        urls.add("http://placehold.it/300&text=3");
        urls.add("http://placehold.it/300&text=4");

        loadImages(0);
    }

    private void loadImages(final int index){
        Target t = new Target(){
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
                Log.w("image", "image received" + index);
                loadImages(index + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable){
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable){
            }
        };

        if(index < urls.size())
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(urls.get(index))
                    .into(t);
    }
}
```